# Can't bake two actions together

Tags: animation, baking

just like the title says. I've followed a tutorial exactly but still the product of baking the "action" and "rotator" action together is not the complete merging of both animations.

Could someone please take a look? Thanks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq6kckhbr6ln7lb/loading%20animation%20one.blend?dl=0

Comment: Checked the file but what exactly U want to achieve? Cause it looks like a merge to me...

Comment: if you bake both "action" and "rotator" into a new action and then delete action and rotator so that only the new action remains the animation is different, right?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please **uncheck** Only Selected option to solve all objects in the scene and **select Object and Pose** too for storing all the scene data. Tested and works for me buddy (as You could see I already removed those Action strips),

Comment: Thank you so much! Probably nothing to be helped but I run into these snags alot and solutions like this don't seem so obvious to me. Did you just play around with it or was there reasoning behind this? Maybe it would help me in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Just tried when saw those options in Bake and find a solution. Please check my answer as correct if so using the checkmark next to it Willem - thank You.